# What is R.ornitholytica? Is it a misspelling of R.ornithinolytica or a different species?

Tags: microbiology, bacteriology

I'm trying to find out which of these is correct, or whether they are different organisms:

```
Raoultella ornithinolytica
Raoultella ornitholytica
```

I have come across both spellings in various articles, papers, etc.  They seem to be used interchangeably, but I'm not sure if they are the same thing, if one is a misspelling of the other, if they are equally acceptable spellings or if they are separate organisms.

Comment: I can't really be sure, but NCBI Genbank only "knows" Raoultella ornithinolytica, the variant ornitholytica does not exist there. So I would guess they are not separate organisms.

Comment: Thanks. Although this shows two results, I can't find them in the linked documents: `https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmedhealth/?term=%22Raoultella%20ornitholytica%22`. I can't find any actual hits in any of the other databases there.

Comment: Probably someone misspelled the keywords for some articles including "ornitholytica". Nobody ever proofreads the keywords I guess.